# How to markAllAsTouched on nested forms triggered from parent form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a recursive nested custom form that can be dynamically added to a parent form implemented using `controlValueAccessor`. When I click the submit button on the parent form, I'd like for all the controls in the nested forms to be marked as touched and show validation errors if any. Using `this.form.markAsAllTouched()` in the parent form obviously doesn't propagate to the nested forms.

How can I achieve this by editing just the custom form? I have tried using `ngDoCheck()` in the custom form as below and it seems to apply touched to any new forms I add but not existing ones, which is the opposite of what I want (new forms should not be added with validation errors).

```
 ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.form.touched) {
      return;
    }

    // get the parent formArray
    const formArray = this.injector.get(FormArrayName).control;

    if (formArray?.touched) {
      this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }
```

Here's my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qnrcz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-form%2Fprofile-form.component.ts).